# Flask - 400 Bad request

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, flask, oracle11g

I have this python code which should take in data from an html form and use it in a WHERE clause:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
def search():
    connect = cx_Oracle.connect("benjamin", "siliyetu", "PRINCE-PC/XE")
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    searched = request.form['search']
    named_params = {'search':searched}
    query = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM edited WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (cod_ed, 
                            :search) OR REGEXP_LIKE (nome_ed,:search) OR 
                            REGEXP_LIKE (endereco,:search) OR REGEXP_LIKE 
                            (telefone,:search) OR REGEXP_LIKE 
                            (cidade,:search)", named_params)

    results = cursor.fetchall()
    posts = list(results)
    return render_template('search.html', posts=posts)
```

and the template I'm using is this(part of the template anyway. Its not the whole thing):

```
<form method="POST" action="/editora" class="form-outline" >
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-offset-6 right">
            <div class="form-group mx-lg-3 mb-2">
                <label for="element-7" ></label>
                <input id="search" name="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar..." />
                <label></label>
                <a class="btn btn-primary " type="submit" href="search">Pesquisa</a>
```

When I try to use the data from the form, it gives me a

```
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'search'
```

But when I input data using input() it works fine. What gives!?

How would I go about fixing this issue? I also want to add some regular expressions in the where clause but its not budging. How do I do that too?

Ps- I'm working with oracle express edition 11g

Comment: On the submit link can you please try adding a backslash such as href=“/search”..

Answer (score 1):

Without having a traceback (you *are* running with the debug server while developing, right?), the exception you're getting comes from the

```
searched = request.form['search']
```

line.

- the HTML example you have POSTs to `/editora`
- the Python code you have has a route `/search` (not `/editora`) and the view won't accept POST requests anyway (`methods=['GET']`).

Are you sure the snippets you've posted are correct?

`request.form` is only populated for POST requests, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit data to *search* route, you form action should point to that route.

```
<form method="POST" action="/search" class="form-outline" >
```

And if you want for a search route to get that data from POST request, you should put in methods 'POST' value.

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

The reason why you get:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'search'
```

1. because you are sending something to the application or server that they cannot handle. (http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest)
2. KeyError is for trying to access dict object parameter 'search' which doesn't exist beucase form is never submited.